# how to export component in react js to use in another project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a simple component `hello world` in `react js` this

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div >
      hello4
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I export in index file like this

```
import App from './App'
module.exports = {
    App
}
```

Now I export this component is `index.js` to use in **another project**

so in another project I used above project as a dependency like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "pubnsi": "git+https://git@github.com/naveennsit/pubs.git",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
```

but when I used this component in my another project like this it gives me **syntax error**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import App from "pubnsi/src/App";
function App1() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
   hello
      <App/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App1;
```

I tried to replicate this bug in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-glitter-bj6sz?file=/package.json

but not getting error in codesandbox.

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "consukmer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "pubnsi": "git+https://git@github.com/naveennsit/pubs.git",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? what is your `main` file in `package.json`?

Comment: syntex error coming ...!! main file is not mentioned..i used `create react app`

Comment: see update ...!!! package.json file

Comment: why are you using `module.exports`? instead of `export`?

Comment: as a module I am exporting this

Comment: I tryied using export also but same error

Comment: and what is your syntax error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214649/discussion-between-user944513-and-tudor-gergely).

Answer (score -1):

To use a Github repository as a dependency, you will have to add it like this:

```
"pubnsi": "naveennsit/pubs"
```

instead of like this:

```
"pubnsi": "git+https://git@github.com/naveennsit/pubs.git",
```

Comment: He *can* add it as `naveennsit/pubs` but he doesn't *have to*